# Build a sequence $x_n$ such that $PL\{x_n\}=[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Build a sequence $x_n$ such that $PL\{x_n\}=[0,1]$. $PL$ of a sequence is the set of partial limits...

I tried using the harmonic series but it wouldn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: what is $PL \lbrace x_n \rbrace $ ?

Comment: I edited it....

Comment: Is a "partial limit" [the limit of a subsequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19099/partial-limits-of-sequence)? Is each $x_n$ a real number? By $PL\{x_n\}$ do you mean the set of partial limits of the sequence? Your question still is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try $  \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

Comment: You mean, taking the fractional part of every element in $\Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: I don't fully understand...

Comment: I mean taking $\lbrace x_n \rbrace = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] $ , because we know, that this set is countable (can be arranged in a sequence).

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that a "partial limit" is the limit of a subsequence, each $x_n$ is a real number, and $PL\{x_n\}$ is the set of partial limits of the sequence.

One possible sequence is
$$1,$$
$$\frac 12,1,$$
$$\frac 14,\frac 12,\frac 34,1,$$
$$\frac 18,\frac 14,\frac 38,\frac 12,\frac 58,\frac 34,\frac 78,1,$$ 
$$\ldots,$$
$$\frac 1{2^k},\frac 2{2^k},\frac 3{2^k},\ldots,\frac {2^k-1}{2^k},1,$$
$$\ldots$$

It's not very hard to come up with a formula for $x_n$: I'll leave it to you.

There are many variations on this, of course. One is to use powers of ten rather than powers of two:

$$1,$$
$$0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,$$
$$0.01,0.02.0.03,\ldots,0.99,1.00,\ldots$$

It should be clear why every real number between zero and one is a limit of a subsequence of either of these sequences.

Let me know if you need more detail, or if you need a sequence where all the $x_n$ are distinct.

Comment: $$x_0=0, \qquad x_{q(q-1)/2+p}=\frac{p}{q} \qquad \text{ for } 1\leq p \leq q\text{ and } q=1,2,\ldots$$